# How to combine integrals of the same function with matching limits in Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

If I have an integral of a function over the interval [a,b] and an integral of the same function over [b,c] then their sum is the integral of that function over [a,c]. [Latex'd up in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C378f.png)

I would like Sympy to recognise and implement this property when dealing with unevaluated integrals.

e.g.

```
from sympy import *
x, a, b, ,c = symbols('x a b c')
f = Function('f')

int_sum = Integral(f(x),[x,a,b]) + Integral(f(x),[x,b,c])

combined_int = Integral(f(x),[x,a,c])
```

In the above code I would like some way to change the symbolic output of `int_sum` into the output of `combined_int`.

In particular, I am dealing with some sums of several integrals of the same functions over intervals that combine into one big interval. I would like to combine these together automatically to avoid having to do it by hand. This seems like a rather simple rule for Sympy to follow but I can't find a way to do it.

I have tried the usual `.doit()`, `.expand()`, `.simplify()` methods on such expressions without the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you collect a list of the lower and upper limits from integrals that should combine (i.e. have same integrand and coefficient) and use [repsort](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/6257#issuecomment-364794533), that will put them in a plausible order. Then step through and find the chain.

```
# define repsort
>>> from sympy import S
>>> from sympy.abc import x,y,z,t
>>> repsort((y,z),(x,y),(z,t),(x,S.One))
[(x, y), (y, z), (x, 1), (z, t)]
```

So the two chains are (x,t) and (x,1). `Integral.limits` will tell you the limit(s). You might make a dictionary `{(coefficient*integrand, integration variable): [(a, b), (c, d), (b, c)]}` to group bounds of related integrals.